# What are the possibilities to add generated html from module in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to debug external module in Magento. In that, when i logged in admin end, I have got pop up with some message and also got one notification message.Installed module generate the code for script to alert the popup message,div to display the notification. This HTML is generated and appended in DASHBOARD page which is having body class as " `adminhtml-dashboard-index`"

I guess there might be some way to push the generated code with dashboard page.

What are the possible ways to add external module notification or some html or generated js script with core module like  DASHBOARD?

Hope you understand my question...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you done a search over the code base for `adminhtml-dashboard-index` ?

Comment: @BOOMER yes i have done all way of search

Comment: I'm absolutely not sure if I understand you right but .. if you want to hack into Magento admin dashboard you just need to override correspondent block class.

Comment: He didnt mentioned anywhere like he is hacking magento, he wanted to remove a notification message , see below @sparcksoft answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to drop a block in there.  Observe the adminhtml_block_html_before event:

```
<events>
    <adminhtml_block_html_before>
        <observers>
            <super_adminhtml_block_html_before>
                <class>super/observer</class>
                <method>beforeAdminHtml</method>
            </super_adminhtml_block_html_before>
        </observers>
    </adminhtml_block_html_before>

</events>
```

Then, create a new block and append it to the notifications block.

```
public function beforeAdminHtml($observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if ($block->getNameInLayout() == 'root') {
        $extendBlock = $this->_createMyNoticeBlock();
        if ($extendBlock) {
            $block->getChild('notifications')->append($extendBlock);
        }
    }
}
```

I used this to insert my own HTML block where the notifications usually show within the header - shows not only on the dashboard but on all the admin pages.